# undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, linker, undefined-reference

I am trying to setup opencv c++ with the help of cmake tool, and here are things that I have done.but I got some error,

my **CMakeLists.txt** is as follow,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(edge VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

# these two line are added by me
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(edge main.cpp)

# this one line is added by me
target_link_libraries(edge ${OPENCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

here is PATH,
[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiRdW.png)

my vscode config **c_cpp_properties.json** is as follows,

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "C:\\opencv\\build\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and my **main.cpp** is just for test (I'll write code later).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(int, char**) {
    cv::Mat src;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and I got some chunky lines on my terminal, here

```
[main] Building folder: edge edge
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build f:/edge/build --config Debug --target edge -j 4 --
[build] [ 50%] [32m[1mLinking CXX executable edge.exe[0m
[build] CMakeFiles\edge.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
[build] F:/edge/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
[build] F:/edge/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] F:/edge/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\edge.dir\build.make:99: edge.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:838: CMakeFiles/edge.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:845: CMakeFiles/edge.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:517: edge] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Actually I want to know why these error ? how to fix.
(I guess some linking issue or something else.)

Note -: currently I am in **windows** environment. (please consider this).

Comment: link to [`OpenCV_LIBS`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html), cmake is case sensitive

Comment: Hmm, this is not working for me, but as I switched to MSVC compiler now it is fine.(may be issue with gcc)